# #include "existing file" fails: no such file (C)

Tags: c, gcc, include, makefile

Compiling C with gcc. 
While

```
#include "/absolute/path/to/my/file"
```

works OK,

```
#include "../../relative/path/to/my/file"
```

fails with "no such file or directory". This only happens when the file is placed outside the project directory. file has read permissions. What could be the reason?

Comment: including the exact code, build command, and file structure will give you better answers

Comment: When moved out of the working directory, is the directory it is placed into reachable from the INCLUDE path used by your compiler? If not, then you're kinda getting what you're asking for.

Comment: Make sure the relative to the directory in which the `gcc` command is invoked - this is not always the directory in which you invoke `make`.

Answer (score 2):

When using the format

```
#include "some_file.h"
```

the preprocessor by default looks in the same directory as the source file, if the file is not found there, it looks in the header-file search paths.

If the header file is not in the same directory as the source file, and not in one of the directories of the preprocessors search-path, then it will not be found.

You *can* write relative or full paths though:

```
#include "../some_directory/some_file.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need [GCC Options for Directory Search](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)

Answer (score 0):

When using gcc and local header files you need to add an include path to your build command.

mysource.c:

```
#include "localfile.h"
```

build command:

```
gcc -o program mysource.c
```

This works as long as the header file is in the same directory as your source (where you're running the command). If your header file is in a different directory you can include with the `-I` option:

```
gcc -I../headerdir -o hello.exe hello.c
```

or an absoulte path:

```
gcc -I/home/user/myprogra/headerdir -o hello.exe hello.c
```